# Directional derivative at the origin of $\displaystyle \frac{xy^6}{(x^4+y^8)}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I'm supposed to find the directional derivative (in all directions) at the origin of $\displaystyle\: f(x,y)= \frac{xy^6}{(x^4+y^8)}.$

I think the answer is supposed to be $0$, but when I take the partial derivatives I still have $0$ in the denominator so I'm not sure how to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: directional derivatives can be found by switching to polar coordinates. Of course, the function is not continuous there, which is the point of the exercise. One sort of behavior along $x = t^2, y = t,$  different behavior along  $x = -t^2, y = t.$

Comment: Your function as written is undefined at the origin. I’m going to guess that wherever you got this problem also stated somewhere that $f(0,0)=0$.

Answer (score 3):

First, let us compute gradient of function $\,f\left(x,y\right) = \dfrac{xy^6}{x^4 + y^8}:$

$$
\nabla f\left(x,y\right)  = \begin{bmatrix}f_x\\f_y   \end{bmatrix}
% = \begin{bmatrix}f_x\\f_y   \end{bmatrix}
,\qquad
\left\lbrace\begin{aligned}
f_x &= \frac{y^6\left(x^4+y^8\right) - 4x^4y^6}{\left(x^4+y^8\right)^2}
= \frac{y^6\left(y^8-3x^4\right)}{\left(x^4+y^8\right)^2}
\\
f_y &= \frac{6xy^5\left(x^4+y^8\right) - 8xy^{13}}{\left(x^4+y^8\right)^2}
= \frac{2xy^5\left(3x^4 - y^8\right)}{\left(x^4+y^8\right)^2}
\end{aligned}\right.\implies
\\
\implies\nabla f\left(x,y\right)
 = \begin{bmatrix}f_x\\f_y   \end{bmatrix}
 = \frac{\left.3x^4 - y^8\right.}{\left(x^4+y^8\right)^2} \begin{bmatrix}-y^6\\2xy^5   \end{bmatrix}$$

Thus, derivative of $\,f\left(x,y\right)\,$ along given vector $\,\vec{\sf v}=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$ can be computed as

$$
f_{\vec{\sf v}}\left(x,y\right) = \left\langle \nabla f, \vec{\sf v}\right\rangle = \frac{\big(2bx - a y\big)\left(3x^4 - y^8\right)y^5}{\left(x^4+y^8\right)^2} 
$$

Hope you can pick it from there. You may have to compute limit as $\,\left(x,y\right)\to\left(0,0\right).\,$